# what are the disadvantages of creating function scope around for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

what are the disadvantages of using the **for loop**  by wrapping it inside of 
function scope { } in **JavaScript** ?

```js
function logs(){ //function scope started
  for(var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    console.log(i); //i accessible
  }
  console.log(i); //i accessible
} //function scope ended
console.log(i); //i not accessible because it was declared in a block scope
logs();
```

Comment: `i` isn't accessible outside the for loop...

Comment: if variable i is not scoped to the loop - isnt it bad?

Comment: if you at carefully, your second **console.log(i)** is giving error.

Comment: *if variable i is not scoped to the loop - isnt it bad?* Not at all. It depends on what your goal is.

Comment: When you are using `var` only, there is no such thing as "block scope", so the `{}` does absolutely nothing and the question makes no sense because adding extra `{}` when using `var` isn't something that anyone does. It's like writing `console.log("test");;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`. Sure, that's legal, but it's not doing anything for you, so no one does it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `var` only, there is no such thing as "block scope", so the `{}` does absolutely nothing and **the question makes no sense** because adding an extra `{}` when using `var` isn't something that anyone does. It's like writing `console.log("test");;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`. Sure, that's legal, but it's not doing anything for you, so no one does it. **It's a mistake in the use of the language syntax that just doesn't cause any errors in this case.**

When you use `var`, the variable is scoped either to the ***function*** it is declared within (and will be available everywhere in that function) or it is ***Global*** if it is not declared within a function.

- With `var`, there is no such thing as "block scope".
- Use `let` to create block scope.

**It is not good or bad to use either one of these. It depends on what your goal is.**

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  for(let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
   console.log(i); //i accessible
  }
  console.log(i); //i is not accessible
} 
console.log(i); //i is not accessible
```

If you declare the variable using 'let' it is limited to the for-block.

```
{
  for(var j=1; j<=5; j++) {
   console.log(j); //j accessible
  }
  console.log(j); //j accessible
} 
console.log(j); //j  accessible
```

If you declare it using 'var' than its declared globally.

Answer (score 0):

The disadvantage is that it is useless unless you declare a block scoped variable in it.

With `var`, the variable is declared at the nearest function scope or the global scope - you could and should omit that extra block.

```
{
  for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    console.log(i); // i accessible
  }
  console.log(i); // i still accessible
}
console.log(i); // i still accessible as well
```

With `let`, the variable is scoped to the `for` loop header and body only - you could and should omit that extra block.

```
{
  for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    console.log(i); // i accessible
  }
  console.log(i); // i not accessible
}
console.log(i); // i still not accessible
```

To make use of the block, you would either have to set up a label and `break` from it, or you need to declare a local variable in it (outside of the loop), for example

```
{
  let i=0;
  for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    console.log(i); // i accessible
  }
  console.log(i); // i still accessible
}
console.log(i); // i not accessible
```

Answer (score -1):

the main disadvantage is that: ***i*** is not scoped to the loop and can be accessed out side of the loop to and not to the loop block.

using **let** instead of **var** will ease things up. so you dont have to create extra code block {}

```js
for(let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  console.log(i); //i accessible
}
console.log(i); //i is not accessible
```

Comment: Why do you believe that this is a disadvantage? It's how the language works. Please see my answer.

Comment: the only disadvantage i could think of was - putting extra pair of { } while using var --- but the let keyword solved it.

Comment: The extra `{}` does absolutely nothing with `var`. As I said, with `var` there is no such thing as block scope. It's not a disadvantage, it's a mistake in syntax.